# Jupyter notebook validation fails: type string schemas

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I created some jupyter notebooks with Google Colab, when trying to open them with Jupyter notebook in local with my mac, I frequently see this error message:

```
Notebook validation failed: {'type': 'string'} is not valid under any of the given schemas:
{
 "type": "string"
}
```

The notebook is saved, but the message is constantly popping up.

It seem that some texts are not validated, maybe because of accented strings.

I would like to know if there are some known causes and solutions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem due to nbformat Please follow this thread :

https://github.com/jupyter/nbformat/issues/166

update nbformat to 4.3.0.

conda install -c anaconda nbformat
updated nbformat to this version, but
conda install -c conda-forge nbformat
installs/updates only version 4.2.0